# loop through each column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have two tables namely ExcelData and PlanProfile . What i want that when i loop through each row of the ExcelData table, logic will insert column_names in the Attribute field of the another table PlanProfile, But I don't want to loop through each column, for some columns there should be normal insertion in second table.

```
ExcelData table:

Id  PId  PType  CId  CNotes  CLegal
1    101  test  201  notes  testlegal
2    102  test  202  notes  testlegal
3    103  test  203  notes  testLegal
```

What I want in Second table PlanProfile;

```
Id PId PType Attributes Value
1  101 test   CId         201
2  101 test   CNotes      notes
3  101 test   CLegal      testlegal
4  102 test   CId         202
5  102 test   CNotes      notes
6  102 test   CLegal      testlegal
----- same goes for 103
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Test Data

```
declare @ExcelData TABLE (Id INT, PId INT, PType VARCHAR(20)
, CId VARCHAR(20), CNotes VARCHAR(20), CLegal VARCHAR(20))
INSERT INTO @ExcelData VALUES
(1  ,  101  ,'test',  '201'  ,'notes','testlegal'),
(2  ,  102  ,'test',  '202'  ,'notes','testlegal'),
(3  ,  103  ,'test',  '203'  ,'notes','testLegal')
```

### Query

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID ASC) New_ID
       ,*
FROM @ExcelData t
 UNPIVOT (Value FOR Attributes IN (CId, CLegal,CNotes))up
```

### Result

```
╔════════╦════╦═════╦═══════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ New_ID ║ Id ║ PId ║ PType ║   Value   ║ Attributes ║
╠════════╬════╬═════╬═══════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║      1 ║  1 ║ 101 ║ test  ║ 201       ║ CId        ║
║      2 ║  1 ║ 101 ║ test  ║ testlegal ║ CLegal     ║
║      3 ║  1 ║ 101 ║ test  ║ notes     ║ CNotes     ║
║      4 ║  2 ║ 102 ║ test  ║ 202       ║ CId        ║
║      5 ║  2 ║ 102 ║ test  ║ testlegal ║ CLegal     ║
║      6 ║  2 ║ 102 ║ test  ║ notes     ║ CNotes     ║
║      7 ║  3 ║ 103 ║ test  ║ 203       ║ CId        ║
║      8 ║  3 ║ 103 ║ test  ║ testLegal ║ CLegal     ║
║      9 ║  3 ║ 103 ║ test  ║ notes     ║ CNotes     ║
╚════════╩════╩═════╩═══════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```

### Note

Columns used in `UNPIVOT` **MUST BE** of the same data type if they are not use a sub-query to cast/convert them to a same datatype and the rest should be the same. In this example columns `CId, CLegal,CNotes` must be of the same datatype.

Comment: Use a CAST inside the UNPIVOT clause to make all the columns of the same datatype if they aren't...

Comment: @M Ali Thanks for your time and help. But I am getting an error on executing as " The type of column "CLegal" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list." even I have columns of same data type in both of the tables.

Comment: use a sub-query before applying unpivot and cast the column to the same datatype as others, see this [`SQL FIDDLE`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/15190)